# Java String automatically assigned null value

Tags: java, string

In the code below, in the first iteration of the first for loop, boxes[a] is automatically assigned a null value.

The remainder of the iterations are fine (user input is accepted). Only the first has the issue where a null value is automatically assigned.

Does anyone know why this may be? Thank you.

```
package testing;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Testing {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);

    int boxNumber;

    boxNumber = in.nextInt();
    String[] boxes = new String[boxNumber];

    System.out.println(boxNumber);

    for(int a=0; a <= boxes.length - 1; a++){

        boxes[a] = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(boxes[a]);
    }

    int packageNumber;

   packageNumber = in2.nextInt();
   String[] packages = new String[packageNumber];

   System.out.println(packageNumber);

   for(int n=0; n <= packageNumber - 1; n++){

        packages[n] = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(packages[n]);

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Add `in.nextLine();` after `in.nextInt()` to consume the `'\n'`. Same for `in2.nextInt()`. That will work after (also why using two scanners?).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java calculator not executing if-statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177801/java-calculator-not-executing-if-statement) or actually [using scanner nextline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032356/using-scanner-nextline)

Comment: Also get rid of 2nd Scanner object (`in2`). It's not needed and under certain conditions could become harmful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario fitting the description of what occurs is when you type in a number on the first line, then the rest of the lines are strings for the boxes.

But the `nextInt()` method doesn't advance past the first newline character, so the first time you call `nextLine()`, it matches on the rest of the line until the first newline character, `""` ( not `null`).

After the call to `nextInt()`, insert a call to `newLine()` before the `for` loop to bypass the first newline character.

```
String firstNewLine = in.nextLine();
for(int a=0; a <= boxes.length - 1; a++){
```

Answer (score 0):

when you did hit enter after entring the first number you also have and empty line that's why nextLine() return empty string, you can use this boxNumber = in2.nextInt(); instead but I would suggest to think of another way, normally you don't need two Scanner instances